# Strange white screen with mirrored black characters while booting UBUNTU

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, plymouth, white-screen

I downloaded the minimal UBUNTU 14.04 from here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

I created bootable USB stick with unetbootin and then I installed whole system on USB stick. I choose only "Install command line" ubuntu. GRUB is placed on MBR.

When I start my new system I got only white screen with strange black strips and every character is mirrored from command line console. Totally unreadable.

But when I hold "shift" key or I reset by button system -> GRUB menu is displayed -> I can select Ubuntu generic -> everything is displayed all right.

I set in /etc/default/grub this:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”text”

and then sudo grub-update. Im using Intel onchip card, so do I really need to install this:

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel

? I want only command line ubuntu, not with GUI.

But it doesnt help! There is some problem with graphical driver because I dont have the GUI installed, I think.. My board is Gigabyte N3050N-D2P.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved it that I installed a newer kernel 3.19.0-49-generic and it works fine.